# How a table produced in a loop can be plotted in the same chart?

Tags: r

I want to produce a loss exceedance curve with the code:

```
x <- rpois (10000, 3) * rlnorm (10000, 100,10)

number_sequence = seq(0.1,1,0.1)
for (i in number_sequence)

{
y  <- quantile (log(x), c(i))
plot (y,i)
}
```

I am getting 10 separated plot charts. The information is right, but I need to have the 10 data points in the same chart to make a curve as (10%, 85), (20%, 91).. (100%, 141) . I failed to make a matrix to plot at the end.

I am happy to technically explain how the formulas work for risk quantification in R.

I have gotten 10 separated plot charts rather than one single chart with the 10 data sets.

Comment: Collect the data inside the loop.  Plot the graph outside the loop.  There's probably no need to use a loop at all.  I can't be sure because it's not entirely clear what you are trying to do.  Please use `set.seed` for reproducibility and supply the data that you want to plot.

Comment: Does `y <- sapply(number_sequence, function(i) quantile (log(x), i));
plot (y, number_sequence)` give you what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y <- c()
for (i in number_sequence)
{
  y  <- c(y,quantile (log(x), c(i)))
} 
plot(y,number_sequence)
```

Or faster:

```
y <- quantile(log(x),number_sequence)
plot(y,number_sequence)
```

Comment: It worked! The code produced many copied charts but it is the information needed for the loss exceedance curve. Many thanks

Comment: Thanks KacZdr! I upvoted it, but my reputation is lower than 15.